# TwitterOAuth: undefined index and undefined property

Tags: php, twitter, oauth, oauth-2.0, twitter-oauth

I'm working with Abraham's twitteroauth to implement Twitter OAuth in my application. While running my application, this is the error I'm encountering:

```
Notice: Undefined index: oauth_token in /opt/lampp/htdocs/twitta/redirect.php on line 432

Notice: Undefined index: oauth_token_secret in /opt/lampp/htdocs/twitta/redirect.php on line 433

Notice: Undefined property: Abraham\TwitterOAuth\TwitterOAuth::$http_code in /opt/lampp/htdocs/twitta/redirect.php on line 435

Notice: Undefined property: Abraham\TwitterOAuth\TwitterOAuth::$http_code in /opt/lampp/htdocs/twitta/redirect.php on line 442
OOOOOPS
```

This is the part of the `redirect.php` file that is raising the above error:

```
require('config.php');

$connection = new TwitterOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET);

$request_token = $connection->oauth(OAUTH_CALLBACK);

$_SESSION['oauth_token'] = $token = $request_token['oauth_token'];
$_SESSION['oauth_token_secret'] = $request_token['oauth_token_secret'];

switch($connection->http_code)
{
    case 200:
        $url = $connection->getAuthorizeURL($token);
        header('Location:' . $url);
        break;
    default:
        echo "OOOOOPS" . $connection->http_code;    
}
```

What seems to be wrong with my code?

EDIT:

As suggested by someone on the comment section, I tried to `var_dump()` the `$request_token` variable, and this is what was outputted:

[image]

All that gets outputted is a jumbled webpage on `var_dump($request_token);`

Comment: Do a `var_dump()` of your `$request_token` variable and see if it contains the `oauth_token` and `oauth_token_secret` members. That seems to be where the problem is coming from.

Comment: @NaijaProgrammer I tried doing that just as you suggested. Do have a look at the edited version of my original post, where I have included the results of `var_dump($request_token);`.

Comment: From the results, you can see that your `$request_token` array doesn't contain the member variables `oauth_token` or `oauth_token_secret`. Infact, it's a numeric-indexed array, whose first element is an HTML document code. Start your debugging from that point.

Comment: You need to read the [documentation](https://twitteroauth.com/redirect.php), that's now how you use TwitterOAuth to get a request_token and `getAuthorizeURL` was removed from TwitterOAuth last year.